# How to output local figure with input box and actionbutton in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm new to rmarkdown and now I want to create a rmarkdown website which has the below function:

There is a selectInput box and one or more actionbutton(here is only one)

I'd like to output the local figure when choosing one input.

But I don't where is wrong with my code chunk.

Here is my reproducible code:

````
---
title: "123"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```
abc {.sidebar } 
=========================================================
<h4>Search with mouse gene symbol, the results will be displayed beside:</h4>
<style>
.shiny-flow-layout>div {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```{r}
#knitr::opts_chunk$set() 
library(rmarkdown)


inputPanel(
      selectizeInput(
        "selectGeneSymbol", 
        "what selected:", 
        choices = "Slc2a1",
        multiple =F,
        width = 360,
        selected = "Sele"
      )
)

actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "plot1")

```


Home {.tabset}
===================================


```{r ,warning = FALSE, message = FALSE,echo=FALSE,fig.height= 6}
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1,
                      {
                        # ![unchanged image](Slc2a1_FPKM.png)
                        knitr::include_graphics(paste0(input$selectGeneSymbol,"_FPKM.png"))
                      })

renderPlot({
p1()
})
```
````

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @RonakShah I don't understand what you mean, sir.  I know how to show it without a   actionbutton . But there are lots of figures so I  hope I can output each image when I select a image name(or gene symbol) in the box and then show the image.

Comment: @RonakShah  Just remove  ![unchanged image](Slc2a1_FPKM.png) out of the code chunk . I think you are kinding me.  There are two methods and you can also use knitr::include_graphics("Slc2a1_FPKM.png") as above method.